# getSelectedItemPosition spinner gives wrong result

Tags: android, android-spinner, selecteditem

When i try to get the selected the position of the selected item with getSelectedItemPosition i always get 0 as result. I created a test with an ItemSelectedListener but it gives strange results. 
Here is my code:

```
this.chooseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.d("TEST", "val1: " + arg2 + " val2:" + arg3);
        Log.d("TEST", "pos: " + ItemOption.this.chooseSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

And the logs give this result:

```
08-08 20:44:58.017: D/TEST(15078): val1: 0 val2:0
08-08 20:44:58.017: D/TEST(15078): pos: 0
08-08 20:45:00.142: D/TEST(15078): val1: 2 val2:2
08-08 20:45:00.142: D/TEST(15078): pos: 0
```

what could be the cause of this problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: get rid of `ItemOption.this.` besides you are getting the correct position in the onItemSelected its `arg2`

Comment: Remove the ItemOption.this. Why would you call getSelectedItemPosition() inside onItemSelected() when you can get the selected position from your "arg2" int - variable?

Comment: The code was just to test if the value would change.
But getSelectedItemPosition() still returns 0 when val1 and val2 return correct results

Comment: so why are you worried about that, just hold onto the value from onItemtSelected

Comment: because every time I want to get the selected index of a spinner I need to write a big block of code instead of 1 line